# How to save dynamic checkbox state after page refresh?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, local-storage

I am trying to save the state of the checkbox even after refreshing the page. I can get the index of each dynamic checkbox so I know which checkbox is checked, however I can't get the checkbox to remain the same even after page refresh. I tried using **localStorage** to save locally, even though it stores the value, it doesn't keep checkbox state the same:

Dynamic Checkbox HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox[$index]" ng-change="alert($index)">
```

Get Dynamic checkbox index:

```
$scope.checkbox = []; //checkbox index
$scope.alert = function(index, event){
  localStorage['checkbox'] = $scope.checkbox[index];
  alert("checkbox " + index + " is " + $scope.checkbox[index]);

}
```

//Check for changes and update

```
localStorage.getItem("checkbox") ? 
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("checkbox")) : false;

$scope.$watch(localStorage['checkbox'], function (newVal, oldVal) {
  if (oldVal !== newVal) {
    localStorage['checkbox'] = newVal;
  }
});
```

Comment: you need to asign the values on init, check if localstorage have info and then asign to each check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this snippet, need to loop from the content of the localstorage if have info and asign to each checkbox.

**SAMPLE HTML**

```
<p ng-repeat="check in checkBoxes track by $index">
  <label>{{$index}}</label>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkBoxes[$index]" ng-change="valueChange()"/>
</p>

<pre>{{checkBoxes}}</pre>
```

**SAMPLE ON CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.checkBoxes = [false, false, false, false];

if(localStorage['checkBoxes']){
  $scope.checkBoxes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("checkBoxes"));
  console.log(localStorage['checkBoxes'].length);
}

$scope.valueChange =function(){
  localStorage.setItem("checkBoxes", JSON.stringify($scope.checkBoxes));
};
```

[Sample Plnkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/iqldEXGGNAUU4IQeakR6/)

Comment: But how does it remember what checkbox I've selected once I've refreshed the page?

Comment: let me do a plnkr.

Comment: Check plnkr, and let me know if that satisfy the use-case.

Comment: Thank you @jesus-carrasco. that is what I was looking for.